# MVC 4 Actionlink Parameter Not Passed To Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, parameters, actionlink

I have a View within my MVC 4 application, whereby the user types in a first and last name and hits the search button. Once they do this, an action in my controller is called

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangeLineManager(RegisterLineManagerModel model, int? id)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
       if (id == null)
       {
         // Search for person using model.SearchFName and model.SearchLName
       }
       else
       {
         // User has selected manager from returned list of people
       }

    }
}
```

Once the user performs a search and if data is returned, I list the data

```
@foreach (var user in Model.LineManagers)
{
  <tr>
   <td>@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Select Manager", 
       actionName: "ChangeLineManager", 
       controllerName: "Portfolio", 
       routeValues: new { id = (int?)user.ApplicantID }, htmlAttributes: null)
   </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Ideally, I would like the user to then click the 'Select Manager' link beside their appropriate manager, however, whenever I test this, nothing happens, the ChangeLineManager action within my Controller is not called.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you using http post in your action method

Comment: @Rex because it's needed when the user first carries out a search, i.e., types first and last name then hits submit button.

Comment: @tgriffths your action method is looking for two variables  RegisterLineManagerModel model, int? id, model and and a Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action link will render to a tag.When user click this tag,GET request go to the server,but in your controller only POST ChangeLineManager.
You need add something like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeLineManager(int? id)
{
    //some logic

}
```